# Find a combination of convex function so that it is positive

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, convex-optimization

A student in my class asked me the following question, I did know what tools will be needed to attack it. But I found it is an interesting question.

Let $f_1,f_2$ be two convex functions on $[0,1]$ and let $\varepsilon>0$. For every $x\in[0,1]$，we have $\max\{f_1(x),f_2(x)\}>\varepsilon$. Does there exist a $\lambda\in [0,1]$ so that
$$
\lambda f_1(x)+(1-\lambda)f_2(x)>0, \quad \forall x\in [0,1]?
$$

Any hints are welcome! Thanks!

Comment: This is a classical question about whether $\sup_\lambda\inf_x$ equals $\inf_x\sup_\lambda$ or not. Since it deals with the convex (in $x$)/concave (in $\lambda$) function $\lambda f_1(x)+(1-\lambda) f_2(x)$, the answer might be in the book *Convex Analysis and variational problems* by Ekeland & Temam

Comment: Following Denis Serre's comment, this holds if $f_1,f_2$ are continuous on $[0,1]$ by von Neumann's minimax theorem, right? In general, they are always continuous on the interior, and in one-dimension (unless I'm missing some pathological example), one should be able to extend $f_1,f_2$ continuously to the boundary while only possibly decreasing the values there (but preserving the maximum assumption by continuity), and then conclude via the continuous case. But I might be missing something...

Answer (score 2):

[image]

**Here is the easiest explanation, two intersecting straight lines satisfy this property, and two intersecting straight lines are the worst-case among all convex functions when fixing the intersection point of the two functions.**

And the following proof is an effort to make the above intuition rigorous and mathematical readable.

---

**The following argument only available for convex function with reasonable regularity**

First, as point out by Loic Teyssier, we need to consider the case  independently: when $f_1,f_2$ do not intersection. And when $f_{1}, f_{2}$ is not intersect and then we can take $\lambda=0$ or 1 to make $\lambda f_{1}(x)+(1-\lambda) f_{2}(x)=\max \left\{f_{1}, f_{2}\right\}$.

Second, as point out by Dieter Kadelka, we need to consider the endpoint $\{0,1\}$ separate because the prove of N-L formula relay the point $a,b$ is in some interval, in the following argument. This can be down use the convex property to gain a lower bound on $f_1(0),f_1(1),f_2(0),f_2(1)$.

Then, this is true and in fact, we can determine $\lambda$. We need the following 2 lemmas.

In the case $\exists \quad x_{0} \in[0,1] . \quad f_{1}\left(x_{0}\right)=f_{2}\left(x_{0}\right)>0$

> $f$ is a continue couvex function on [0.1], then $f$ is lipschitz function.

> $f$ is a lipschitz function. then $f^{\prime}(x) \quad$ exist a.e. in $[0,1]$ and $\forall \quad 0\leq a< b\leq 1$,
> $$f(b)-f(a)=\int_{a}^{b} f^{\prime}(x) d x$$
> We can understand the previous N-L formula in distribution to avoid unnecessary trouble（The derivative does not exist, the left and right derivatives are not equal, and the derivative is zero but the function is a strictly monotonic function）

then $\forall x \in[0.1]$,
$\begin{aligned} \lambda f_{1}(x)+(1-\lambda) f_{2}(x) &=\lambda\left(f_{1}\left(x_{0}\right)+\int_{x_{0}}^{x} f_{1}^{\prime}(t) d t\right)+(1-\lambda)\left(f_{2}\left(x_{0}\right)+\int_{x_{0}}^{x} f_{2}(t) d t\right) \\ &=\lambda f_{1}\left(x_{0}\right)+(1-\lambda) f_{2}\left(x_{0}\right)+\lambda \int_{x_{0}}^{x} f_{1}^{\prime}(t) d_{t}+(1-\lambda) \int_{x_{0}}^{x} f_{2}^{\prime}(t) d t \end{aligned}$

Now $\quad$ WLOG $\quad$ we assame
$f_{1}(x)>0$ When $0 \leqslant x \leqslant x_{0}$, $f_{2}(x)>0 $ when $ x_{1} \leqslant x \leqslant 1$, and assume $f_{1}^{\prime}\left(x_{0}\right)>0. f_{2}^{\prime}\left(x_{0}\right)<0$.
When $ 1 \geqslant x>x_{0}$. Then,

$$
\begin{array}{l}
\int_{x_{0}}^{x} f_{1}^{\prime}(t) d t \geqslant\left|x-x_{0}\right| \cdot f_{1}^{\prime}\left(x_{0}\right) \\
\int_{x_{0}}^{x} f_{2}^{\prime}(t) d t \geqslant\left|x-x_{0}\right| \cdot f_{2}^{\prime}\left(x_{0}\right)
\end{array}
$$

When $0 \leqslant x<x_{0}$, then,
\begin{array}{l}
\int_{x_{0}}^{x} f_{1}^{\prime}\left(t) d t \geqslant\left|x-x_{0}\right| \cdot f_{1}^{\prime}\left(x_{0}\right)\right. \\
\int_{x_{0}}^{x} f_{2}^{\prime}(t) d t \geqslant \left|x-x_{0}\right| \cdot f_{2}^{\prime}\left(x_{0}\right)
\end{array}

So take $\lambda$ solve $\quad \lambda f_{1}^{\prime}\left(x_{0}\right)+(1-\lambda) f_{i}^{\prime}\left(x_{0}\right)=0$, then $\quad \lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda) f_{2}(x) \geqslant 0 \quad \forall \quad x\in [0,1]$.

---

**To prove the property is true for the general convex function we may follow the argument above and modified the detail(especially the H-L formula part) by use supporting lines of $f_1,f_2$ and observe convex functions lie above their supporting lines.**

Comment: $f_i'$ need not exist (only the right and left derivatives) and $f_i$ is not necessarily continuous, only on $(0,1)$. But I think that does not really matter.

Comment: Dieter Kadelka : yes I do not check the details, but it is enough that NL-formula is true and we do not need the derivative of $f_i$ exist everywhere and we allow it blow up at several point(it can only blow up at countable many point because a fixed convex function is bounded variational)

Comment: For the functions $f_1=-a\cos(\pi x)+\epsilon, f_2=a\sin(2\pi x)+\epsilon$, for some  $\epsilon$ and $a$ such that $|f_1|,|f_2|<1$, we get $\cos(\pi x)[2(1-\lambda)\sin(\pi x)-\lambda] >-\epsilon$. And for very small $\epsilon$ , we can see that there is no $\lambda <1$ for which the inequality is always satisfied.

Comment: it is not convex right?

Comment: Oh, Yes. It's mentioned in the question.I didn't see it.

Comment: I don't understand why your first lemma holds. Take $f_1=1$ and $f_2=2$...?

Comment: Loïc Teyssier : Sorry it is just not hold, fortunately, when it is not hold then $f_1,f_2$ is not intersect and then we can take $\lambda=0$ or $1$ to make $\lambda f_1(x)+(1-\lambda) f_{2}(x)=\max\{f_1,f_2\}$.

Comment: To make your arguments exact you should also consider the case that  $f_i$ need not be continuous at $0$ and $1$,

Comment: Dieter Kadelka:Thanks for point out, in this case, we need to consider it separate because the prove of N-L formula relay the point $a,b$ is in some interval.